# Can I use MailChimp's API 3.0 to remove a large number of subscribers from an Interest Group?

Tags: mailchimp, mailchimp-api-v3.0

I have about 38,000 subscribers in an Interest Group. Using segments I identified around 9,000 subscribers that I'd like to remove from that Interest Group. On the MailChimp website it is incredibly cumbersome to remove them. You can only select a maximum of 100 at a time(only 100 show up on a page before needing to click to the next one). And once you click `Actions > Remove from Group` they remain in the auto-updating segment making it very difficult to select only the ones you haven't done yet.

Can MailChimp's API let me do this faster?

Answer (score 0):

Yes! MailChimp allows you to send Batch Update queries which you can use to unsubscribe users from the mailing list.

Answer (score 0):

You can use MailChimp's [batch endpoints](http://developer.mailchimp.com/documentation/mailchimp/reference/batches/) to make a series of PUT requests updating those subscribers fields. So each individual operation would be made against a lists members instance ([documented here](http://developer.mailchimp.com/documentation/mailchimp/reference/lists/members/#edit-put_lists_list_id_members_subscriber_hash)).